# Netherrack, paranormal events, and C418-11: prank, mod, expected?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft on a server and a weird thing happened when I started placing netherrack on the roof of my house.  I heard ominous sounds I hadn't heard before so I decided to run inside for safety.  When I got to the door it started opening and shutting repeatedly.  When I got inside the house a stone block appeared in the room and slowly broke down to nothing and the music stopped.  I went back outside and found a burnt looking music disk on the ground, C418-11.  I played it and confirmed it was the sounds I was hearing.

So, I'm wondering is this a normal way to get C418-11, is there a spooky mod that is doing this, or did someone with special privileges go invisible, play the music, and then prank me?

I've tried placing more netherrack around with no effect.

Comment: What server were you playing on?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms truevanilla.mymc.io

Comment: This (or a variation of it) is going on my list of pranks to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone was trolling you if you were on a Vanilla Minecraft server. It could have been an admin or an OP. I don't believe any mods can do things like this.

Comment: It is (semi) vanilla. How did they go invisible?

Comment: Potions or maybe a moderator used a command to do that.

Comment: Most likely potions, I played on a server where the mods would constantly check my base for banned items and they did this by popping an invis pot and searching through all of my chests. I was banned shortly thereafter for attacking the invisible mod, thinking it was some sort of mob I had no knowledge of.

Answer (score 2):

Someone went to ... *some* lengths to pull that off. A jukebox in Minecraft can be heard from [up to ~60 blocks away](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Jukebox) (while the Wiki says approximately 65, I've found it to be about 60). So, this is what they probably did:

1. Placed a jukebox far enough away that you didn't notice them, but heard the song, then inserted the disc.
2. Had a *second* copy of c418-11 and a piece of smooth stone
3. Managed to sneak by you using an extended potion of invisibility (brewed with redstone to increase duration)
4. Placed the stone block and punched it into cobble in front of you, after dropping the second copy of the disc
5. Sprinted back out of sight before the potion wore off, picked up the jukebox

You got lucky, if they managed to sneak a piece of smooth stone, they could have just as easily had a lava bucket, or a spawn egg that would have been quite difficult to deal with.

If you're going to be playing on a server where quite a bit of fun can be had in pranks, I recommend installing SecurityCraft. It's got (among insanely over-powered land mines) these cool portable radars that can alert you to another player coming into a predefined proximity, fake water (which is actually lava) and fake lava (which is actually water). There's also better doors and locking mechanisms to keep prying eyes out of your stuff.

Anyway, my point - it could have been just another player and not an admin / op of the server, just using things available in vanilla. Hence, anyone with a brewing stand is a suspect (or those known to associate with those potion-brewing pranksters!)

Comment: It seems a little suspicious how much you know about this...

Comment: @BrianNickel Well, it's not a hard prank to reverse engineer once it's been described. To come up with? Yeah, it was pretty brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

An admin mod or owner played the music disk and trolled you.  If you were on a low server it was probably the owner and if it is a popular server it was probably an admin.